# How to group repeated row values in a column

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

```
t_no name value
1    a     45
1    b     23
1    c     5
1    a     12
1    b     99
1    c     6
```

I need to show my above table as

```
no  name value1 value2
1   a    45      12
1   b    23      99
1   c    5       6
```

Comment: This is called a pivot table, but you can't do it in your example because you have no clear criteria for which value belongs in which column.  "First" has no meaning in a relational database, because sets have no implicit order.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create dynamic columns in mysql alone, either in scripting language, or you can use group_concat to have them in one column:

```
  SELECT to_no, name, GROUP_CONCAT(value) 
  FROM table GROUP BY to_no, name
```

result:

```
 no  name value
 1   a    45,12
 1   b    23,99
 1   c    5,6
```

Comment: thank u. need to list duplicate data in column. can we try in stored procedure

Comment: to look up duplicates you can add, after GROUP BY ..., HAVING count(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have a pivot function, but you can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression. Since you have multiple values for each `t_no` and `name`, then you could use user defined variables to assign a row number to each group of values:

```
select t_no, name,
  max(case when rn=1 then value end) value1,
  max(case when rn=2 then value end) value2
from
(
  select t_no, name, value, 
    @rn:=case when @prev=t_no and @c=name then @rn else 0 end +1 rn, 
    @prev:=t_no,
    @c:=name
  from yourtable
  cross join (select @rn:=0, @prev:=0, @c:=null) c
  order by t_no, name
) d
group by t_no, name
order by t_no, name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df85f/4)